# Why do I have to use return in this Palindrome check?

Tags: java, recursion

Below are two recursive pieces of code with two different functions.

**[1]** My **check Palindrome using recursion** code is this:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class CheckPalindromeRecursion {

public static boolean recursion(String pal) {
    if (pal.length() == 0 || pal.length() == 1) {
        return true;
    } else if (pal.charAt(0) == pal.charAt(pal.length() - 1)) {
        return recursion(pal.substring(1, pal.length() - 1));
    }
    return false;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    System.out.println("Enter the String for check:");
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    String str = scan.nextLine();

    if(recursion(str))
        System.out.println(str + " is a palindrome");
    else
        System.out.println(str + " is not a palindrome");

    scan.close();
}}
```

**[2]** My **reverse a number using recursion** code is this:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ReverseNumberRecursion {

public static void reverse(int numb) {
    if (numb < 10) {
        System.out.print(numb);
        return;
    } else {
        System.out.print(numb % 10);
        reverse(numb/10);
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    System.out.print("The number you want to reverse is: ");
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    int numb = in.nextInt();
    in.close();

    System.out.print("The reversed number is: ");
    reverse(numb);

}}
```

Why did I had to use a **return** in  - **[1]:** `return recursion(pal.substring(1, pal.length() - 1));` but I did not need to use a **return** in - **[2]:** `reverse(numb/10);`?

Comment: because the one has a returntype, the other is declared as void. read up on the basics before trying to implement logic

Comment: In [2] the line `return;` has no effect. `return` breaks the method at this point, but there is no code after it.

Comment: howlger, thank you. That makes sense

Comment: `reverse` should have been called `printReverse` since it does not return the reverse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because of the param in the function

```
public static boolean recursion(String pal) -> returns data of type boolean 
public static void reverse(int numb) -> doesnot return any data so intialize with void
```

Return statement is based on the user requirement whenever we want to use data of particular function in another function we use return

Comment: Yes but why do I need to use 'return recursion()' and not just 'recursion()'? I want it to "loop" around again, meaning that in my head the only returns necessary would be the 'return true' and 'return false'

Comment: You are using a recursive function in which the function calls it self

Comment: If you didn't `return` the result of the recursion the metgod would return`false` for all longer than 1 chars  arguments regardless if they are palindrome or not.